# what is diference between map, and for_each to collect a BTreeMap?

Tags: rust

I have a struct that has a field that is a `BTreeMap` whose value is another struct that implements `From<&[u8]>`

```rust
MyStruct {
    ...
    btree: BTreeMap<String, MyOtherStruct>
    ...
}
```

`MyOtherStruct` implements `From<&[u8]>` because i'm recovering it from a file.

```rust
impl From<&[u8]> for OtherMyStruct {
    fn from(stream: &[u8]) -> Self {
        ...
    }
}
```

I read the file that has a list of `MyOtherStruct`, and I have a function that parses the stream and returns an array of streams, which represents the streams of each struct `MyOtherStruct`

```rust
fn read_file(path: &PathBuf) -> Vec<u8> {
    ....
}

fn find_streams(stream: &[u8]) -> Vec<&[u8]> {
    ....
}
```

Then to build `MyStruct`, I take the array of streams and for each stream I create `MyOtherStruct` from the stream

```rust
fn main() {
    let file_content = read_file(PathBuf::from("path"));

    let streams = find_streams(&file_content);

    let mut my_other_structs = BTreeMap::<String, MyOtherStruct>::new();

    // here is where i collect my items
    streams.iter().for_each(|s| {
        let item = MyOtherStruct::from(*s);
        my_other_structs.insert(String::from("some key"), item);
    });

    ....
    ....
}
```

The question is in the part where I collect my items. Before using a for_each I used a map but the compiler gave me an error that said `the trait 'FromIterator<IndexEntry>' is not implemented for 'BTreeMap<std::string::String, IndexEntry>'`.

Of course I understand what the compiler error refers to, so I copied the signature of the trait I needed, pasted it into the editor and implemented it.

```rust
impl FromIterator<MyOtherStruct> for BTreeMap<String, MyOtherStruct> {
    fn from_iter<T: IntoIterator<Item = MyOtherStruct>>(iter: T) -> Self {
        let mut btree = BTreeMap::new();

        iter.into_iter().for_each(|e| {
            btree.insert(String::from("some key"), e);
        });

        btree
    }
}
```

so, then instead of doing it this way

```rust
    let mut my_other_structs = BTreeMap::<String, MyOtherStruct>::new();

    streams.iter().for_each(|s| {
        let item = MyOtherStruct::from(*s);
        my_other_structs.insert(String::from("some key"), item);
    });
```

it looked something like this

```rust
    let my_other_structs = streams.iter()
        .map(|s| MyOtherStruct::from(*s) )
        .collect();
```

My question is, beyond cosmetics, is there any significant difference in the way things look on the back end? When assembling my `BTreeMap` one way or the other.

I mean I love how it looks when I do it with the `FromIterator` and just use a `.map` where I need it, but internally I do a `for_each` and it's the same thing I'm doing the other way without augmenting a `.map` on top of it.

so is there any relevant difference in this case?

Comment: What was the code that caused the error?

Comment: I am strongly against implementing `FromIterator` with your own types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map().collect()` is more idiomatic for a couple of reasons. For one a simple `for` loop is recommended over the use of `for_each` [by it's own documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.for_each) unless it makes the code possible or more readable.

The second and more important reason is `.collect()` can and will use size hints of the iterator where it can and preallocate the storage needed, so it will perform as good or better than `for_each(insert)`.

Your `FromIterator<MyOtherStruct>` implementation could also be streamlined using the existing `impl<K, V> FromIterator<(K, V)> for HashMap<K, V>` like this:

```rust
impl FromIterator<MyOtherStruct> for BTreeMap<String, MyOtherStruct> {
    fn from_iter<T: IntoIterator<Item = MyOtherStruct>>(iter: T) -> Self {
        iter.into_iter()
            .map(|e| (String::from("some key"), e))
            .collect()
    }
}
```

Or depending on your actual uses just do that directly instead of implementing `FromIterator` in the first place.